# Remove "Suggestions" from Google Drive app

Tags: google-drive

I can successfully [turn off Suggestions from the Google Drive website](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/remove-suggestions-and-suggested-files-from-google-drive?expand_article=1), but I cannot find how to remove them from the Home screen of the Google Drive Android app. (The site I linked suggests a way that does not work.) My searches suggests that [this might not be possible](https://support.google.com/drive/thread/163871391/how-do-i-turn-off-suggestions-in-google-drive?hl=en). Does anyone have a solution for me?